# How to define database connection in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, swagger-codegen

I have done a lot of R&D on swagger. I want to build API in swagger and want to define database connection string inside swagger but till Now I have not found any tool in swagger which can do that. I just want to know whether there is any tool in swagger that can provide interface to establish database connection

Comment: Swagger is dedicated to describe a restful API interface. So its not expected to include the feature you mentioned

Comment: @DanielTran Thanks for response

Comment: so how are people using a db with swagger?